# How external interfaces work in OMNETPP/INET?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I have been trying in the past few days to build and run a very simple network to no avail (most of the network I try to build is borrowed from extServer example). No matter my configuration in terms of IP addresses, routes etc. I cannot seem to make it work.
I have seen many people struggling with it, but have not found any solutions posted anywhere. The readme file in the Emulation folder of INET is more confusing than helpful.
Hence, I would like your help in making the following simple network work and, hopefully, even make it (the post) a tutorial for others as well.

The network I want to build (could not be simpler):

```
External Server <----> [ext0] ROUTER [ppp0] <----> [ppp0] Standard Host
```

My setup:

- Software:

  - OMNET++ 4.6 with PCAP enabled.
  - INET Integration head (includes several features that I like).
- OS:

  - Xubuntu in VirtualBox as a guest which hosts OMNET++. The reason for using Virtualbox is that my Host Win 7 machine refuses to run any external interface example with the error "cSocketRTScheduler: couldn't set socketopt for raw socket.". I modified the source a bit and used WSAGetLastError function, which resolved the issue as "The requested address is not valid in its context.".
  - Back to VirtualBox :)
    Xubuntu has one network interface set to Host-only networking with IP address 10.0.0.1 and netmask 255.255.255.0 .

Standard Host Setup in omnetpp.ini:

```
**.server.numTcpApps = 1
**.server.tcpApp[*].typename = "TCPSinkApp"
**.server.tcpApp[*].localAddress = "172.0.1.111"
**.server.tcpApp[*].localPort = 10021
```

The standard host is using the same server.mrt from extServer example.

The router.mrt is as follows:

```
ifconfig:
# interface 1 to server
name: ppp0
    inet_addr: 172.0.1.100
    Mask: 255.255.255.0
    MTU: 1500
    POINTTOPOINT MULTICAST

# interface 2 to external server (real network interface)
name: ext0
    inet_addr: 10.0.0.2
    Mask: 255.255.255.0
    MTU: 1500
    POINTTOPOINT MULTICAST
ifconfigend.

route:
#Destination     Gateway          Genmask          Flags  Metric  Iface
172.0.1.111      172.0.1.100      255.255.255.255  H      0       ppp0
10.0.0.1         10.0.0.2         255.255.255.255  H      0       ext0
0.0.0.0          *                0.0.0.0          G      0       ext0
routeend.
```

Any ideas on how to make this network work are really welcome as, should it work, I want to expand it later. Also, I would greatly appreciate it if any suggestions are in step-by-step style.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have just tested the client example yesterday. As the client example is much more simple I suggest to test that one first. If you can ping into the omnet simulation running extClient, then move to extServer.

Comment: As for the raw socket issue. Are you sure that you run the simulation as 'Administrator'?

Comment: Hi Rudi, thanks for the reply. I will try with extClient first, as I think I finally understood the instructions about routing and I may update the post if it runs correctly.
I am sure that I run the simulation as "Administrator" on Windows; somehow I have a feeling that it cannot find the external device by its name, as on Linux I never get that error. Any suggestions on that matter?

Comment: I was able to set up the client example. So I can help on this one if you have specific questions. I was able to set it up on my local machine (not in a virtual box). Some tips: route add 10.0.0.1 gw 192.168.1.72 (where this last address is my ethernet card's IP address). The other trick was that the ping was NOT working from my own machine to the simulation host. The reason is that those ping requests were routed through the local loopback interface (instead of the ethernet if where the simulation is bound), so I had to ping into the simulation from a different host.

Comment: I also had success with VirtualBox with extClient. For extClient I kept the default IP 10.1.1.1 for the emulated host and added a route as you did, just a bit modified: route add 10.1.1.0 gw 10.0.2.15 (the last is the IP of the emulated machine). Then, I could just ping without any problems straight from the same host. I think, I can close the topic and move on with other more crucial parts that I want to implement (possibly another topic). Thank you very much for everything.

Comment: Regarding Windows and the Raw Socket error, I believe it is related with the raw sockets themselves. Microsoft has limited the functionality of raw sockets for its normal OSes after Winxp except the server ones. Winpcap tries to bridge this gap and should of course work, but probably there is something weird going on. I wish I could try OMNET and INET on a Windows server and see if it makes a difference.