# HIL prototype using OMNeT++/INET external interfaces – error

Tags: omnet++, inet

I've been trying to implement a simple prototype for hardware-in-the-loop (HIL) simulations using OMNeT++/INET external interfaces. My test network consists of an Arduino Ethernet sensor, and a simulated subnet including an INET router and an INET standard host. The external sensor sends UDP datagrams every N seconds.(One-way UDP protocol and the server in this case is a pure UDPSink which does not send any requests.)

This test is similar to the INET "emulation" examples, and the one discussed in a recent post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243890/how-external-interfaces-work-in-omnetpp-inet), but I've never seen any mentions of the error I'm getting right now.

I'm are running the tests on an Ubuntu v. 12.04 LTS Linux machine using OMNeT 4.6 and INET 2.6. The simulation seems to throw an error before it starts processing any datagrams:

`Error in module (IPv4) UdpSensor.extRouter.netWorkLayer.ip (id =29) at event#3, t=0: check_and_cast(): cannot cast (cMessage *)UdpSensor.extRouter.netWorkLayer.ip.BIND to type 'cPacket *'`

I would appreciate any advice. I can post the details of my network setup, and we’d be happy to contribute to writing documentation for configuring & using OMNeT++/INET external interfaces, and on how to use OMNeT++ for real-time HIL simulations.

Comment: This is most likely an issue with the IPv4 implementation were some data packet arrives it did not expect at that point in time. It would be useful to know the exact location of the exception. Would you be able to run it in the debugger? When the exception occurred the debugger will stop and you could examine the stack trace and see at what exact code location in IPv4.cc the casting is done. That would at least give some context.

Comment: Sure will do. I'm new to OMNeT simulations and forums so I posted the same question on the Google Groups forum and that one includes my project configuration files.

Comment: I'm trying to understand whether it's a simple oversight in my project or IP configuration or something else. The error occurs after a couple of run steps when the simulated router receives a BIND message. Before actual data exchange with the external sensor starts. I also tried the TCP protocol in the same setup and received the same error with ip.timer instead of BIND

Comment: I cannot launch the simulation in debug mode as a super user, the IDE says it cannot run gdb “for an unknown reason”. I still have to figure out why. But when I run it I see that several cMessages get scheduled at the start: IP register commands, and then a UDPBindCommand named BIND (with the local port value set in control info), and Join Multicast Group.

The simulated network consists of a server and extRouter. In the Inspector window I see that the  BIND has src=server.udpApp (id=10) and dest=server.udp (id=11). So why would it even reach extRouter netWorkLayer.ip, id=29?

Comment: @Rudi The debugger started working somehow, so I could set a breakpoint at IPv4::handleMessage. It shows that two Register Protocol messages are handled correctly. But when it receives BIND it calls AbstractQueue::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) and a type cast error is thrown in:

else if (!msgServiced) {
        cPacket *msg2 = arrivalWhenIdle( PK(msg) );
}

Pls help me understand what’s wrong:-(

Comment: @Rudi I made it work.. UDP datagrams generated by an Arduino sensor now flow thru a router ext interface to a simulated host/server. The BIND command gets processed by the UDP app layer on the server as I think it should. I had to make a change in the INET linklayer.ext.cSocketRTScheduler class though. In the getNextEvent method I commented out  an msgQueue.removeFirst() call at the end. Other schedulers e.g. the base scheduler and RT scheduler in the OMNeT socket example don't remove messages from the queue, they only call peek.